# Ubuntu phone office abilities

Tags: ubuntu-touch, libreoffice, phone, microsoft-office

what options are there to edit and view MS-Office documents (Excel, "doc", "Ppt") at Ubuntu phone?

There's really no information on the topic in reviews.

Comment: *Editing* and viewing MS Office documents in an Ubuntu phone still needs some work. [Proof Of Concept: LibreOffice’s Writer Tool Running On Ubuntu Touch](http://linuxg.net/proof-of-concept-libreoffices-writer-tool-running-on-ubuntu-touch/). From the linked webpage: *For now, this is only a proof of concept, LibreOffice is identical with the desktop version and so, it is almost impossible to be used on the mobile platform.* For document viewing also see [Ubuntu Touch Document Viewer wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/DocViewer).

Comment: Possible that one is duplicate of this. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than web apps such as Office 365 or Google Docs, there are currently no options to edit Microsoft Office documents on an Ubuntu phone.

This may change as the devices begin flowing into retail channels, and will change as development on convergence begins to show fruit in Ubuntu 15.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, where LibreOffice and all desktop apps will run natively on the phone on user request, even if the interface is not optimal.

Comment: is there any video, a screencast, showing how does Google Docs work for Ubuntu phone; and how does Office365. Maybe it's enough.

Does it have an offline mode?

Comment: No, you'd just open up the Browser and go to the respective web site.